# How do I create a formula for "if x ≥ then multiply by y" and so on?

Tags: excel, if-statement, range, excel-2007

I've only used Excel for the basics.

I want to multiply the contents of the cell by a different number depending on the value in the cell. I have these ranges:

- 0 - 499, then multiply by 0
- 500 - 999, then multiply by 1
- 1000 - 1499, then multiply by 4

I was able to figure out the formula `=IF(C21>=10000,C21*1)` for if a value in cell `C21` is greater than or equal to 10,000, but I don't see how to extend that to multiple ranges.

How can I write a formula to handle the multiple ranges I've listed above?

Answer (score 7):

You can use another `IF` in the `ELSE` part of the expression, evaluation will stop as soon as a `TRUE` condition is met;

```
=A1 * IF(A1 < 500, 0, IF(A1 < 1000, 1, IF(A1 < 1500, 4, 0)))
```

(The last 0 is the case when the value is > 1499)

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested IF statements for doing ranges:

```
=IF(C21>=500,IF(C21>=1000,IF(C21<1500,C21*4,'dontknowwhatyouwanthere'),C21*1),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about nested Ifs?

```
=IF(A1<1000;IF(A1<500;+A1*0;+A1*1);+A1*4)
```

Then you've got:

If it's **less than 1000** another if:

- If it's **less than 500** You do the " *** 0** "
- If it's **not** (*you are at 500-999 range, from the first if*) You do the " *** 1** "

Else it's **not less than 1000**:

- You have your " *** 4** "

Answer (score 0):

I used this formula and it worked:

```
=V4*IF(V4<600,0.2,IF(V4<800,0.22,IF(V4<1000,0.25,IF(V4<10000,0.27))))
```

Comment: Please don't add _"thanks"_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).